# Transformar un array de objetos en un objeto que contenga como array cada llave

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

quiero trasnformar un array de objetos a un objeto que contenga sus llaves.
Les muestro con un ejemplo

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
const dataSource = [
{ position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
{ position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
{ position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
{ position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
{ position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
{ position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
{ position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
{ position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
{ position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
{ position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];
```

y quiero transformarlo en algo asi:

```
const dataSource = {
   position: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
   name: ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron', 'Carbon', 'Nitrogen','Oxygen', 'Fluorine', 'Neon'],
   weight: [1.0079, 4.0026, 6.941, 9.0122, 10.811, 12.0107, 14.0067, 15.9994, 18.9984, 20.1797],
   symbol: ['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F', 'Ne'],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

La idea es la siguiente:

1. Creas un objeto vacío `output` donde guardarás tus arrays por claves.
2. Por cada elemento de tu array original, iteras en sus claves.
3. Si la clave no existe en tu objeto de salida, la creas en ese momento en forma de arreglo.
4. Si la clave existe, simplemente agregas el elemento actual al arreglo.

Un ejemplo con `.foreach` sería:

```js
const dataSource = [
    { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
    { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
    { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
    { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
    { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
    { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
    { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
    { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
    { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
    { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

let output = {}
dataSource.forEach(data => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (output.hasOwnProperty(key))
            output[key].push(data[key])
        else
            output[key] = [data[key]]
    })
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: Elegante solución

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que uses [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) por cada item que deseas obtener, algo como esto:

```js
const dataSource = [
    { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
    { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
    { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
    { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
    { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
    { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
    { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
    { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
    { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
    { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

const mapIds = dataSource.map(item => item.position )
const mapNames = dataSource.map(item => item.name )
const mapWeight = dataSource.map(item => item.weight )
const mapSymbol = dataSource.map(item => item.symbol )

console.log([mapIds, mapNames, mapWeight, mapSymbol])
```

Comment: Estoy buscando en lo posible que sea escalable.
No siempre van a ser "position", "name", "weight" o "symbol"

Comment: ¿Tu json siempre va a cambiar? Es decir, ¿tendrá un formato diferente cada que envíes algo nuevo?